# What skill level do AI use in Demo Mode?

Tags: mario-tennis

The Special Modes menu in Mario Tennis for N64 has a Demo Mode where you can watch computer cpponents play against themselves. I wanted to watch a match with MAX difficulty CPUs, but Demo Mode doesn't let me set player difficulty levels.

What difficulty level are computers set to during Demo Mode?

[image: Selecting Demo Mode]